# is it possible to limit the size of uncompressed zipped files in unix?

Tags: php, unix, unzip

i am implementing a service where i have to extract a zip file which was uploaded by a user.

in order to avoid disk overflow, i have to limit BOTH zip file size AND unzipped files size.

is there anyway to do that (check unzipped files size) BEFORE unzipping?
(for security reasons).

i am using unix, called from a PHP script.

Comment: One of the zip file headers contains the uncompressed size of the archive.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29#File_headers

Comment: isn't that value can be manipulated? i am trying to fix a security issue where an infinite straight of the same char will uncompressed into infinite disk space (while zip file is quite small).

Comment: A CRC value is associated with the header.  In most cases, the check would fail if the uncompressed size were manipulated.  While this is not perfect security, I think it is the fastest way.

Comment: Yes, as Kevin says, the info is (usually) in the zip file directory.  If there is no tool to extract it it would not be hard to write one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're working in PHP, use its [ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.zip.php) library.

```
$zip = zip_open($file);
$extracted_size = 0;
while (($zip_entry = zip_read($zip))) {
    $extracted_size += zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry);
    if ($extracted_size > $max_extracted_size) {
        // abort
    }
}
// do the actual unzipping
```

You might want to put a limit on the number of files as well, or add a constant amount per file, to take into account the size of the metadata for each file. While you can't easily get a precise figure for that, adding a few hundred bytes to a couple of kilobytes per file is a reasonable estimate.

Comment: Looks like the [official example for `zip_entry_filesize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.zip-entry-filesize.php) is *actually* a function that can be used right away to check for zipbombs.

Comment: can't believe i dived into shell commands while the answer was few lines in PHP :) i assumed shell commands will be more flexible but this seems to be the correct answer.